# Laplace transform of $\sin(\sqrt t)$

Tags: laplace-transform, transformation

How can I use this differential equation
$$4tf''(t) +2 f'(t) +  a^2 f(t)=0$$
 to show that 
$$L(\sin(\sqrt{t}))=\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\pi}\,\frac{1}{s^{\frac{3}{2}}}\,e^{\frac{-1}{4s}}$$

Comment: I guess you mean the Laplace transform of $f(t) = \sin(\sqrt{t}) 1_{t \ge 0}$. if you know the Laplace transform of $f''(t)$, what is the Laplace transform of $t f''(t)$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINTS:**

Note that $f(t)=\sin(\sqrt{t})$ is a solution to the differential equation

$$4tf''(t)+2f'(t)+f(t)=0$$

Let $F(s)$ represent the Laplace Transform of $f(t)$. Then note that Laplace Transform of $tf''(t)$ is given by

$$\mathscr{L}\{tf''(t)\}(s)=-s^2\frac{dF(s)}{ds}-2sF(s)+f(0)$$

Now solve a simple ODE for $F(s)$.

**NOTE:**

Solution to the ODE without prescribed conditions (e.g., initial conditions) has the general form $f(t)=A\sin(\sqrt{t})+B\cos(\sqrt{t})$.  Therefore, if one is restricted to the ODE only to find the Laplace Transform of $\sin(\sqrt{t})$, then all we can say is that

$$\mathscr{L}\{\sin(\sqrt{t})\}(s)=Ae^{-1/(4s)}s^{-3/2}$$

Comment: Thanks. My mistake was that I applied Laplace on the given DE, and it gave me 0.

Comment: You're welcome!  My pleasure Zarmina.  -Mark

Comment: Thanks for such an explanatory and clear answer. I'm following the book "Integral transforms and their applications by lokenath and bhatta and here I'm restricted to use the DE to solve
$$L(\sin(\sqrt t))$$
. In the question we are not given any Initial conditions. The question as I posted is exactly the same as in the book. But our answer has a constant A. How can now I find the value of A. May be the authors used some other method :). –

Comment: You're quite welcome Zarmina!  It was my pleasure and pleased I was able to help you.  To find $A$, we need some additional information beyond the solution to the ODE.  The most straightforward way is to directly compute the Laplace transform of $\sin(\sqrt{t})$.

Comment: Thanks. I hate when authors put restrictions :)

Answer (score 1):

I think it is faster to use the series definition of $\sin t$ and the Laplace transform of $t^{n+\frac{1}{2}}$, or just the definition of the Laplace transform:

$$ \int_{0}^{+\infty}e^{-st}\sin\sqrt{t}\,dt = \int_{0}^{+\infty} 2t\sin(t)e^{-st^2}\,dt = \text{Im} \int_{0}^{+\infty} 2t\, e^{it-st^2}\,dt. $$
The last integral can be computed by setting $t=\frac{u}{\sqrt{s}}$ and completing the square.

Comment: Yes, in fact if one is restricted to the ODE only, then all we can say is that $\mathscr{L}\{\sin(\sqrt{t})\}(s)=Ae^{-1/(4s)}s^{-3/2}$.  That said, the last integral can indeed be evaluated by completing the square.  But, this way forward does require one to deform the contour by applying Cauchy's Integral Theorem.  So, while conceptually a very easy way forward, it does require a bit more to ensure rigor.  ;-)) Just curious, how are your studies going?  -Mark