# How can you evaluate $\operatorname{Im} \int_{0}^{\infty} 2te^{it}e^{-st^2} dt$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

I am trying to find the Laplace transform of $\sin(\sqrt t  )$ by using the definition as suggested here https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1751841/758796. In order to do that, I have to solve the above integral for which the suggestion is to make the substitution $t=u/\sqrt s$ and then complete the square, but I am having trouble with this last step. Can you please do it?

Comment: "Solve" is the wrong word here. One solves problems; one solves equations; one _evaluates_ expressions.

Comment: You can use known identities for   derivatives of Fourier transform of integrable functions.

Comment: Thanks, Michael.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll give a loose, hand-waving overview. You'll need to do some more work to make all of this rigorous and obtain a complete solution.

The square to be completed is in the exponential within the integrand. You'll have
$$\exp\left\{ i\frac{u}{\sqrt{s}} - u^2 \right\}.$$
Notice that
$$u^2 - \frac{i}{\sqrt s}u = \left( u - \frac{i}{2\sqrt s} \right)^2 + \frac{1}{4s}.$$
Therefore,
$$\exp\left\{ i\frac{u}{\sqrt{s}} - u^2 \right\} = e^{-\frac{1}{4s}}\exp\left\{ -\left( u - \frac{i}{2\sqrt s} \right)^2 \right\}.$$

Noting this and letting $I = \int_0^{+\infty} 2te^{it}e^{-st^2} \ dt$, you'll get
$$I = \frac{2}{s}e^{-\frac{1}{4s}}\int_0^{+\infty} u\exp\left\{ -\left( u - \frac{i}{2\sqrt s} \right)^2 \right\} \ du.$$
We'll now make another change of variables $w = u - \frac{i}{2\sqrt{s}}$. You'll arrive at
$$I = \frac{2}{s}e^{-\frac{1}{4s}}\int_0^{+\infty}w e^{-w^2} \ dw + is^{-\frac{3}{2}}e^{-\frac{1}{4s}}\int_0^{+\infty}e^{-w^2} \ dw.$$
You can evaluate these integrals in a straightforward way:
$$I = \frac{1}{s}e^{-\frac{1}{4s}} + \frac{i\sqrt\pi}{2}s^{-\frac{3}{2}}e^{-\frac{1}{4s}}.$$